# check tensorflow version in CMake

Tags: tensorflow, cmake

I'm trying to check the TensorFlow (built from source) version in CMake.

If TensorFlow is built from source, there's a *include* ("eager", c_api.h, c_api_experimental.h, LICENSE) folder, and a *lib* (libtensorflow.so, libtensorflow_framwork.so) folder.

I tried find_package because of PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION variable. Although TensorFlow_FOUND variable was set, PACKAGE variable was not set. Maybe there needs something like .version file.

The reason I'm trying to do this is for a version check. My program needs tensorflow 1.10. If there is pre-built tensorflow already in user(`/usr/include`, `/usr/lib`), it should check version if it is 1.10.

Is there any good method for doing this?

Comment: this is my thought come up to my mind. During CMake, I can run a python script. So, output tf.__version__ is used to check the version.. Of course, I should add python library..

Comment: Above comment is wrong. folder just have c_api files.. there is no kind of python file. So above method is impossible.